# SQL Bind multiple fields condition as AND clause

Tags: mysql, join, in-clause

Can someone help me with this SQL.

Output must always join the day_ids as multiple condition.

For instance, if we choose day_id IN (0,2,4), it must return ONLY all data with day_ids (0,2,4). It works fine.

So when we input (0,2,4,5), it must not return any data. This is where the issue occurs.

Since IN clause follows the OR statement, it still gives the same result instead of returning NULL.

Sample data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rXjOPxFRmtDjdyD4bDvULP-m38G5GvIB/view

Video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WM42cmmMe1nCusqacJNS_MI2t9szgZGn/view?usp=sharing

Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWfdy.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Ala.png

Comment: are they only 3 rows?

Comment: Its dynamic. user may fill-in all 7 days of the week. like (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) as day_ids. Its all or nothing. if the given day_ids doesn't found the exact match and length of the given parameters, it must display null.

Comment: can you provide example data

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rXjOPxFRmtDjdyD4bDvULP-m38G5GvIB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you explain your usecase a little bit? Maybe there can be a better approach, since it's not very common requirement to return null if any of the values you specify don't exist in the table

Comment: hi  Riddhijain, I've attached a sample data and video. Please see on my post. Yeah right. not a common requirement at all.

Comment: I saw it and understood your requirement, but maybe instead of sending your desired "must exist" day_ids to the query, you can handle it outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM vw_transfer_sched WHERE day_id in (0,2,4,5)
GROUP BY week_num, day_id, teacher_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct day_id) = 4;
```

Comment: It returned null thats fine. But when I go back to the original query and add the COUNT, it also gives null which supposedly will return a match. Still it didnt meet the expected output.                                                                                
SELECT *
FROM
  vw_transfer_sched
WHERE
  day_id IN (0,2,4)
GROUP BY
  day_id
HAVING
  COUNT(distinct day_id) = 3

Comment: You may consider using `GROUP BY` on another column.

Comment: What i have in mind is using a SELECT and sub-query from another table(s) or views. As I frequently use before. But still cant figure it out.

Comment: Would you like to try this and give us the result `SELECT * FROM vw_transfer_sched WHERE day_idIN (0,2,4) GROUP BY teacher_id HAVING COUNT(distinct day_id) = 3` ?

Comment: Hi @Aymen. it doesn't work. Ive already test that query earlier. By the way, Ive attached a sample data and video. it returned few matched but not the exact (0,2,4). There are few data which return 0 and 2 but no 4.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM vw_transfer_sched  CASE WHEN day_id IN (0,2,4) THEN day_id ELSE Null END;`
That should give you Null if there are no rows containing 0,2,4

Comment: No. Coz if thats the case, using the IN operator will do the job easily. its actually the same as using the OR. the IN performs like a shortcut method. My concern is more on having an equivalent of the IN operator. but instead of working as OR operator, will work as AND. the reverse method.

Comment: I know it would be the same as IN (0,2,4) perhaps you need to improve your question then, as from what i read you want the rows where day_id = 0 2 4 , unless you want only the last 3 rows that answer should work, and you can replace the OR with IN (...)

Comment: Made an edit to the answer, but you most likely need only the last rows to be checked, you can try adding the other conditions back in date >= current_timestamp() might fix it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 select t.*  
 from 
 ( SELECT * 
   FROM teacher_availability_list 
   GROUP BY week_num,  teacher_id, day_id
   order by week_num, teacher_id ) as t    
group by week_num,  teacher_id 
having group_concat(t.day_id)='0,1,2'
```

Comment: i'll give it a try.

Comment: Hi BUcorp, it only returns data with day_id = 0. It supposed to display all teachers with days_ids based on the parameters given. like If I include (0,2), will only display all teachers with day_ids 0 AND 2. There is no data exist for day_id 5 and 6. so if I add (0,2,5), it must return null. since only 0 and 2 exist.

Comment: are you changing also the count(*)= <according to num of days>  into the having?

Comment: yes of course. it must have the same length. so if we say (0,2,4), count must be 3.  if we have (0,1,2,3,4), count must be 5.

Comment: please check the workaround. I used i different approach.To identify exactly the group i treat it like a string

Comment: Code-only answers might not be very helpful to OP or future viewers of this answer. Good answers include some explanation of _why_ this answer works and _what the OP got wrong_.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending your desired must exits day_ids to the query, you can find out if all those day_ids exist with help of a different query and compare it outside and if they all exist then you can run the query that you have attached.

You can compare the result of the following query with your desired must exist day_ids.

> select group_concat(distinct day_id)
> from teacher_availability_list
> where day_id in (0,2,4,5)

With the table that you have attached it will return 0,2,4.
you can do this outside of the query or in a stored procedure.

IF (result of the above query) = the desired must have day_ids

then -> run the query

else
return null

Comment: What i have in mind is using a sub-query as a result taken from another table(s) or views. Use it as in the main Query. As I frequently does. I'll try your idea.